# Can't open text file in Visual studio while debugging in virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-2013, permissions, virtual-machine, parallels

I tried to search for the problem on google but didn't manage to find anything useful.
I'm working with a MacOsx with Parallels running Windows 8.1, I installed Visual Studio 2013 and set the Project Default Location in

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2013
```

so that is a local location.
The problem is that when I try to debug a program which need to read a text file, such file is not read properly.
The text file is in the same folder of the executable.
Strange thing is, if I navigate to that directory with the cmd.exe and try to run the executable, the file is correctly read.

That prevents me to use the debugger, because when I try to use it the file is not read.
What kind of problem is that? Any clue about how I can solve it?

EDIT: After some searches, I think this could be related to .NET Trusted folders.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: @raptor5000 Yes I am, I also checked the fopen err return code and it is 2, which corresponds to 
"2 ENOENT No such file or directory.  A component of a specified pathname did not exist, or the pathname was an empty string."