# UNICODE compliant converter from text file to binary file in C with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, io

I'm working on a C converter from text file to binary file in Visual Studio, and I want it to be UNICODE compliant.

I pass as argh[1] the input text file, and as argh[2] the output binary file

This is the code

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#ifndef _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#endif
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 100

typedef struct asd{
    DWORD id;
    DWORDLONG regnum;
    TCHAR name[MAX_CHAR];
    TCHAR surn[MAX_CHAR];
    DWORD mark;
} type_line;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *f_in;
    DWORD id = 0, mark = 0, nW = 0;
    DWORDLONG regnum = 0;
    HANDLE fout;
    type_line l;
    int res;

    // open input file
    f_in = _tfopen(argv[1], _T("r"));
    if (f_in == NULL) {
        _tprintf(_T("Error while opening file %s.\n"), argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // open output file
    fout = CreateFile(argv[2], GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (fout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        _tprintf(_T("Error while creating file %s.\n"), argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (_ftscanf(f_in, _T("%d%ld%s%s%d"), &(l.id), &(l.regnum), l.surn, l.name, &(l.mark)) != EOF) {
        _tprintf(_T("%d "), l.id);
        _tprintf(_T("%ld "), l.regnum);
        _tprintf(_T("%s "), l.surn);
        _tprintf(_T("%s "), l.name);
        _tprintf(_T("%d "), l.mark);
        BOOL bolean = WriteFile(fout, &l, sizeof(type_line), &nW, NULL);
        if (bolean) {
            _tprintf(_T("vero\n"));
        }
        else {
            _tprintf(_T("false\n"));
        }
    }

    fclose(f_in);
    CloseHandle(fout);

    // reread file
    fout = CreateFile(argv[2], GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (fout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        _tprintf(_T("Error while opening output file\n"));
        return 3;
    }

    _tprintf(_T("Read the binary file:\n"));
    while (ReadFile(fout, &l, sizeof(type_line), &nW, NULL) && nW > 0) {
        _tprintf(_T("%d "), l.id);
        _tprintf(_T("%ld "), l.regnum);
        _tprintf(_T("%s "), l.surn);
        _tprintf(_T("%s "), l.name);
        _tprintf(_T("%d\n"), l.mark);
    }
    CloseHandle(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

The code build without errors, but when I run it the result is that the input file is correctly opened, but no fields are read from it.

This is the input file

```
1 1000 Rossi Mario 25
2 2000 Verdi Giacomo 23
3 3000 Giallo Carlo 28
```

What is that I am missing?

EDIT: The code is now working. What is super strange is that if i condense the parameter print all in one single printf, the code crashes, while if I print them the way I do (with separate printf's) all is working correctly. Anybody knows why is that?

EDIT2: I solved the problem by changing the declaration of regnum in the struct type_line from

```
DWORDLONG regnum
```

to

```
DWORD regnum
```

Comment: I think you need to read more about the [`scanf_s` family of functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), because you are missing a couple of arguments. And why not read into the structure fields directly?

Comment: surn and name need to be followed by the sizes of the arrays in your _ftscanf_s calls.

Comment: Also be careful about checking the return value of `scanf` (and related functions) with only `EOF`, it can return other values too (for example if there's not enough fields in the input).

Comment: thank you, I changed the _ftscan_s in 
`_ftscanf_s(f_in, _T("%d%ld%s%s%d"), &id, &regnum, surn, _countof(surn), name, _countof(name), &mark)` but it doesn't read anything.  What could be also?

PS: I edited the code in the op also

Comment: Have you tried checking what the `_ftscanf_s` function *actually* returns? Have you checked what `WriteFile` returns? Have you tried stepping through the code to check what happens?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok, I deleted the while statement and replaced with just a single call to `_ftscanf_s` followed by a call to `WriteFile`. The scanf return 5 (which is correct) and the WriteFile return true. Everything working ok.
The problem must be in the while statement.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to debug because of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978252/cant-open-text-file-in-visual-studio-while-debugging-in-virtual-machine?noredirect=1#comment49989640_30978252)

Comment: The code is now working, I edited the op with the working code and also with what was the problem. Which is a very strange one.